# Connecting to clickhouse on remote server fails with weird address

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have a clickhouse server running on Linux subsystem for Windows on a Windows 2016 server. I've setup firewall rules for both inbound and outbound connections on both `9000` and `8123` ports. I used the default config. When I try to connect remotely got this exception:

```
DB::Exception: User default is not allowed to connect from address ::ffff:10.201.1.2
```

How should a user config look like so that a remote connection goes through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue by myself.

I noticed that by default there is a `allow_only_from_localhost.xml` file inside the `dbms\src\Server\user.d` directory. So I thought I should remove this file and everything is going to work. It did not help, but I got inspired and moved my `networks.xml` file into the `dbms\src\Server\user.d` directory and TA-DA! remote connection finaly started working. Aside from relocating the file, I also adjusted its content, so that it matched the syntax from `allow_only_from_localhost.xml` file. It did not matter, Whether I kept the `allow_only_from_localhost.xml` file in the `dbms\src\Server\user.d` directory or not, remote connection worked in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

In the users.xml configure the networks settings

```
<networks>
    <ip>::/0</ip>
</networks>
```

In config.xml uncomment

```
<listen_host>::</listen_host>
```

Comment: Isn't this the default setting in the users.xml?

Comment: i just had to add `<listen_host>::</listen_host>` in `config.xml` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow access from external networks for default user. Add

```
<networks>
    <ip>::/0</ip>
</networks>
```

to default user configuration. More details [here](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/Server/users.xml#L48).

Also it should be enabled by default.

Comment: That I had and the exception still arose, I also tried multiple values such as: `::/0` `10.201.1.2` `::ffff` `::ffff:10.201.1.2` `::ffff:10.201.1.2.`